# Aligning Columns to Achieve `ls -l` Style Listing with find

Tags: linux, bash, files, find, ls

I'm trying to achieve the same format of listing that I get from `ls -l` when using `find`. Albeit with the full path name at the end rather than the filename. FWIW I'm using `find (GNU findutils) 4.5.11`.

I've found the `-ls` flag, which is nice, but it spaces the columns much more than `ls -l`, which is not useful, especially with a full path name at the end, as it is very likely to push the results on to two lines and makes it difficult to read them. For example...

```
$ find /example -ls
  7439    4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 example    example        1579 Oct 26  1985 /path/to/first/file/that/was/found
   530    4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 example    example         122 Oct 26  1985 /path/to/second/file/that/was/found
```

So while that does the job, I want to do better. Looking at the `-printf` flag for `find`, it seems the same thing can be achieved. So far I have `-printf '%M %u %g %p\n'` which is great, and I can customise which info I want and add the others in there. But...

**The problem is, how can I align the columns?**

When the user and group names are a different length, this doesn't work so well. For example...

```
$ find /example -printf '%M %u %g %p\n'
-rwxr-xr-x root root /path/to/first/example/file
-rwxr-xr-x example example /path/to/second/example/file
```

How can I solve this? Preferably using only `find`, but piping to something else would be ok if it's not possible. The man page for `find` doesn't seem to have any option for this using `-printf`.

Comment: You could pipe the find output into `column -t` but if there are spaces in the filenames, the result will be wrong

Comment: That's awesome, thanks, especially because it's very easy to use, keeping the spaces in filenames caveat in mind. In my case that should rarely be an issue. Perhaps put this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specifiers of `-printf` in GNU `find` takes width and alignment (etc.) qualifiers, just as the `printf()` C function, meaning you can align the data left or right and, crucially for your current project, allocate a certain width for the data.

Default output:

```
$ find . -printf '%M %u %g %p\n'
drwxr-xr-x kk wheel .
-rw-r--r-- kk wheel ./.zshrc
-rw-r--r-- kk wheel ./file
drwxr-xr-x root wheel ./rootstuff
-rw-r--r-- root wheel ./rootstuff/SECRET
-rw------- kk wheel ./.viminfo
```

Specifying widths (6) for user and group columns (right-justified):

```
$ find . -printf '%M %6u %6g %p\n'
drwxr-xr-x     kk  wheel .
-rw-r--r--     kk  wheel ./.zshrc
-rw-r--r--     kk  wheel ./file
drwxr-xr-x   root  wheel ./rootstuff
-rw-r--r--   root  wheel ./rootstuff/SECRET
-rw-------     kk  wheel ./.viminfo
```

Same, but left-justified:

```
$ find . -printf '%M %-6u %-6g %p\n'
drwxr-xr-x kk     wheel  .
-rw-r--r-- kk     wheel  ./.zshrc
-rw-r--r-- kk     wheel  ./file
drwxr-xr-x root   wheel  ./rootstuff
-rw-r--r-- root   wheel  ./rootstuff/SECRET
-rw------- kk     wheel  ./.viminfo
```

With file sizes in bytes, allocating 5 digits (zero-filled, because just showing how it could be done):

```
$ find . -printf '%M %-6u %-6g %05s %p\n'
drwxr-xr-x kk     wheel  00512 .
-rw-r--r-- kk     wheel  00000 ./.zshrc
-rw-r--r-- kk     wheel  00095 ./file
drwxr-xr-x root   wheel  00512 ./rootstuff
-rw-r--r-- root   wheel  00000 ./rootstuff/SECRET
-rw------- kk     wheel  00922 ./.viminfo
```

Note that the `ls` command may well allocate widths for its columns dynamically based on the actual need whereas your `find -printf` command would have to use static widths, unless you run `find` twice to first compute the needed space for each column and then again to actually format the output (this is why the `find -ls` output is so wide, it does not use a two-pass approach and instead just gives each column ample space in the hope that everything will align somewhat nicely).

---

Of course, if you don't have many thousands of files, and you *just want a listing of everything*, recursively (i.e., you don't need to filter or do something else with the found pathnames in `find`), you could just use `ls`:

```
$ ls -d -l **/*
-rw-------  1 kk    wheel  922 Jul 25 23:46 .viminfo
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel    0 Jul 19 23:39 .zshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 kk    wheel   95 Jul 25 23:51 file
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  512 Jul 26 00:00 rootstuff
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    0 Jul 26 00:00 rootstuff/SECRET
```

This relies on the `**` globbing pattern being available, which it is by default in the `zsh` shell, and in `bash` if you use `shopt -s globstar`.  It also relies on the shell matching hidden names.  The `zsh` shell will do this if you set the `GLOB_DOTS` option with `setopt GLOB_DOTS`, and `bash` does it with `shopt -s dotglob`.

This would not work if your globbing pattern expands to a list so long that it generates an "Argument list too long" error.

This output would be different from the ordinary `ls -l -R` output in that directories would not be listed individually with breaks between them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking and hoping for. Appreciate the clear and detailed explanation. Can cope without the dynamic column widths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple alternative

```
$ find example -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Comment: Yes, this would work too, but note that `find` may invoke `ls` several times if you do it this way and that the columns in the output may have different widths each time. One of the issues in this question was that the columns needed to be aligned.

Comment: True.  But the original issue was about readability.  So a change in alignment now and then shouldn't be a problem.  But that point is worth mentioning.